# Silverlight 3 - Accessing TreeView Item's parent object

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, treeview

I'm using a TreeView along with a HierarchicalDataTemplate to display a Hierarchical listing returned from a webservice.  Depending on search criteria, this listing can get to be very long and several nested levels deep.  It would be useful to display a "map" of sorts to the user so that they can see where in this listing they are relative to the top level.  The model used to create the hierarchy looks like this:

```
public class IndexEntry
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
    //More properties that define attributes of this class

    //Child objects of the hierarchy are stored in this property
    public List<IndexEntry> SubEntries { get; set; }      
}
```

As you can see, the hierarchy is built using a List of IndexEntry types.

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class IndexEntriesViewModel
{
    //TreeView ItemsSource is bound to this collection
    public ObservableCollection<IndexEntry> IndexList { get; set; } 
    //More properties to define the ViewModel
}
```

As you can see, the TreeView's ItemsSource would be bound to the ObservableCollection of IndexEntry types.  I don't see any obvious way to access the parent object as things are now.   I am considering the option of adding another property in the model that would point directly to the parent object of that particular entry.  This would ultimately allow me to walk up & down the hierarchy and grab what I like as I need it.

So, the question is - Can anyone think of a better way to accomplish this?  Is there a property in the TreeView itself that I'm missing that will provide this ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy solution in the July 2009 release of the Silverlight Toolkit, the GetParentItem extension method in TreeViewExtensions.

1. Download and install the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).
2. Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit (which can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Jul09\Bin).
3. From the method you want to get the parent (I'm going to use the SelectedItemChanged event by way of example):

   ```
   private void OrgTree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
   {
       if (e.NewValue != null)
       {
           var parent = ((TreeView)sender).GetParentItem(e.NewValue);
           if (parent != null)
           {
               Status.Text = "Parent is " + parent.ToString();
           }
       };
   }
   ```

There are quite a few great extensions hiding in there that I'd encourage you to explore for setting the selected item, expanding nodes and getting the containers of items.

Comment: Shawn.  I've been on vacation for a while and have been focused on other things when not.  I have downloaded the new toolkit and in fact, had implmented a number of the extensions manually at one point.  I need to make some time and check out the newer extensions and see where they lead.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

TreeViewExtensions works for me to find the treeviewitem and parent object. View the bottom page for final.

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/65277.aspx